# Geocoding and Search API v7

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I am trying to use Geocoding and Search API v7, Where I can search using category that are mentioned in

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-places/places-category-system-full.html

My question is, can we get the category list. At TomTom they provide the list as JSON file, can I get it from HERE in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Place API to search the POIs based on category. The format is

```
https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places?app_id=xx&app_code=xx&at=52.50449,13.39091&pretty
```

For more details refer : https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/resource-place-categories.html